# Os emojis não aparecem ao executar a função emo::ji() no R

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Não consigo visualizar os emoji do pacote `emo` do `R`  quando gero um arquivo no rmarkdown.

Faço desta forma:

```
emo::ji("smile")
```

Não aparece nada e não reporta nenhum erro.

Desta outra forma:

```
tibble::tibble(emo::ji("smile"))
```

Resulta o output:

```
<chr><U+0001F604>
```

Comment: Qual output do documento, pdf ou html? Como pdf passa par LaTex não será tão fácil quanto html. Aqui em html funciona corretamente. Ainda, aproveita para editar a questão com a parte do código que você está tendo problema com um exemplo reproduzível.

Comment: É um documento em pdf . Por enquanto não encaixei o emoji no relatório, preciso que ele apareça no output primeiramente. Obrigado @WillianVieira!